# return odd/even number in C with multiple numbers

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm trying to write a program that will take two numbers and depending on their values, return both are odd, both are even, or A is odd and B is even, etc.

I managed to get the program to check one variable but if I add in the second variable I get an output that I don't expect and I can't seem to be able to arrange the code to give the correct output.  I'm guessing that it is a problem with the arrangement of the if/else statements.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int numA, numB;
    printf("Please enter variables:");
    scanf("%d, %d", &numA, &numB);
    if (numA % 2) {
        printf("Variable A:%d is odd \n",numA);
    }
else{
    printf("Variable A:%d is even \n", numA);
}
if (numB % 2) {
    printf("Variable B:%d is odd \n",numB);
}
else{
    printf("Variable B:%d is even \n", numB);
}
return 0;
}
```

The output I get is below

```
Please enter variables:4 5
Variable A:4 is even 
Variable B:32767 is odd
```

Why is variable B:32767 not 5?

Many thanks for the help as ever.  If I can sort this out, hopefully I can figure out the rest for myself.

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf` before using those variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `scanf` format expects the numbers to be separated by a comma,

```
scanf("%d, %d", &numA, &numB);
```

but your input wasn't, so only the first number was converted by `scanf` and the second was uninitialised.

You should always check the return value of `scanf` and friends to verify that the correct number of conversions was made.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Always watch out for the comma's. Check